# No upgrade available for 19.04 from 18.10

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 19.04

I'm pretty new to running linux, but I know that 19.04 was released today and I wanted to upgrade from my current 18.10. However, when I follow the release notes here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes#Official_flavour I get the message "The software on this computer is up to date". I made sure that my update settings are set to "any new version" and "normal" in the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Side note: I had to disable this PPA: http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu because it would cause errors in apt updating. Do I need to re-add it? If so how do I do so without it giving me an error?

Edit: I have followed the procedure recommended in the documentation which is identical to the suggested duplicate, but I am not given the option to upgrade. I have not yet tried the

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

option as I don't want to upgrade to the developer version.

Comment: I was under the impression that it took a few days for upgrades to become available. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to make a backup of current system to prevent data loss.

Then do the following:

1. Make sure that you have the following contents in the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:

   > Prompt=normal

   or from *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) GUI tab *Updates*:

   > [image: for any new version]

   set *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* to *For any new version*.
2. Switch to the *Main server* in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`):

   [image: main server]
3. Install all updates to your Ubuntu 18.10 by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
4. Reboot and then use one of the solutions

   - GUI solution:

     ```
     update-manager
     ```
   - terminal solution:

     ```
     sudo do-release-upgrade
     ```

Notes:

1. This method ended with warning message:

   > **Could not install 'linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic'**
   >   The upgrade will continue but the 'linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
   >
   > triggers looping, abandoned

   and I have to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before reboot to prevent lock-up of new 19.04. Maybe it is VirtualBox guest issue. Reported as [bug 1825420](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1825420).
2. really I'll recommend to wait 2-4 days for official stable method with any mirror.

Comment: I also tried switching servers before I posted with no luck. I guess I'll wait a few days before I pursue this further. Thanks for the detailed reply though!

Comment: My system [is upgrading now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLl5a.png).

Comment: So is mine! I guess the fix was patience.