# How can I upgrade to Kubuntu 19.04 from 18.10?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04

Nothing is showing up when I use the usual way of upgrading.

Why?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1135027/66509 . Currently upgrading Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 on VM using my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu documentation website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiscoUpgrades/Kubuntu):

> Note: Upgrades may not become available until several days after the
>   official release.

When the upgrade is eventually available for you, be sure to carefully follow the procedure step-by-step on that page. As a new user, you should also form a habit of reading the release notes of major OS upgrades, which in this case can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10

To upgrade on a desktop system:

Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings.

Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".
Press Alt+F2 and type in `update-manager -c` into the command box.
Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '18.10' is available.
If not you can also use "/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk"
Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

Good luck.